Numerical evaluation of monomial divided differences
Suppose $f(x)=x^{n+1}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and define the divided difference $$f[a,b]=\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}.$$
I am wondering about the best way to numerically evaluate $f[a,b]$ to high precision, when
i) $n$ may be large
ii) $a,b\in(-1,1)$ or $a,b\in (0,1)$
iii) $a$ may be close to or even equal to $b$, with $f[a,b]$ replaced with $f'(b)=(n+1)b^n$ at $a=b$.
I know
$$f[a,b]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{k}b^{n-k}$$
and this seems like it should be numerically stable but slow for large $n$. For $a$ moderately but not extremely close to $b$, it seems like replacing $f[a,b]$ with $f'(b)$ might lead to a large truncation error. I have also thought about using a Taylor expansion for the numerator of $f[a,b]$ and writing $f(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}f^{(k)}(b)(a-b)^{k}/k!+f^{(m+1)}(\xi)(a-b)^{m+1}/(m+1)!$ which would allow cancelling the $a-b$ in the denominator to get
$$f[a,b]=\sum_{k=1}^{m}f^{(k)}(b)(a-b)^{k-1}+\dbinom{n+1}{m+1}(\xi)^{n-m}(a-b)^{m}$$
but I'm not sure how to get a usable bound for the error term. If this problem has been studied before, a reference would also be appreciated.

Related on scicomp.se: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/42376

Define $M=\pmatrix{a&1\\0&b}$.
In general $f[a,b]$ is the top-right entry of $f(M)$ where $f$ is the function $f$ extended to matrices. (See Higham's book for info on functions of matrices.)
In your case you want the top right element of $M^{n+1}$ which you can get by multiplication and repeated squaring in $O(\log n)$ steps. There are no subtractions involved so it should be numerically reasonable.
You can make it more efficient - no need to compute and use that zero in the bottom left. This is analogous to automatic differentiation - which it becomes when $a=b$.
Also see Kahan and Fateman.

Great answer! A related technique for more general functions is discussed in this answer by Lutz Lehmann and the linked paper.

Oh, the Kahan paper probably ought to go into an answer to that question too.

Just key Idea not an answer to your question:
Given $f(x)=x^{n+1}$, the divided difference $f[a,b]=\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$ can be written as $f[a,b]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{k}b^{n-k}$. For $a=b$, use $f[a,b]=f'(b)=(n+1)b^n$. When $a$ is close to $b$, use the Taylor expansion: $f[a,b]=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} b^{n+1-k} (a-b)^{k-1}$. To ensure numerical stability and efficiency for large $n$, compute $f[a,b]$ using Horner's method: $f[a,b] = b^n + a(b^{n-1} + a(b^{n-2} + \cdots + a(b + a)\cdots))$. For reference i may suggest to you  Numerical Analysis, 9th   by Richard L. Burden and J. Douglas

Can you point to a more specific place in Burden and Douglas' book? It's nearly 900 pages long.

I notice that your first three lines are already mentioned by the OP as something they already know. What does your answer add apart from suggesting to compute $f[a,b]$ using Horner's method and recommending a large textbook in numerical analysis? Perhaps the latter two points would be better as a comment on the original post instead, since, as you say, it's not actually an answer, and you don't need the first three lines of content.
